# how can i show a conroller class in class_diagram? and what roles does it have?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

i can't understand how a controller class can exist inside of a class diagram?
and if it is possible what roles does it have and how can i detect such a thing?
what design patterns can i find about deploying controller classes in class_diagrams?
can any body define a controller class for me i think its kind a redundant.

```
//this part is not a part of my question
//it was a quality check and i have to increase my question characters 
//i don't know this is enough or not
//so first try
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Controller classes are just like any other classes, so I don't understand what is the problem

Comment: control class that handle any event from outside and specify which class should handle that.

Answer (score 1):

A controller is just like a regular class in your class diagram. To explicitly say that it is a controller, you can add a stereotype, like `<<Controller>>` for the controller class.

I found some examples on the internet [here](http://epf.eclipse.org/wikis/openuppt/openup_basic/guidances/concepts/entity_control_boundary_pattern,_uF-QYEAhEdq_UJTvM1DM2Q.html), and [here](http://rollerjm.free.fr/pro/Struts11.html), and I am sure there are many more out there.